# Typescript convert string[] to string

Tags: angular, typescript, type-conversion, type-assertion

I have an Angular 5 application and i have a candidate object which has a string[] property, specified in the interface it implements. The actual value of the property is being retrieved from the template, as an input string. This is the problem. 
The object needs to be saved into the database as an array of strings like this:

```
{ candidate.skills: ["c++", "java", "etc"] }
```

However, the value from the input field in the template comes as a string. But typescript thinks it is a string[] as specified in the interface of the object.
So, i cant split the candidate.skills into an array.

Is there a way to do this ? If so, i didnt find it yet.

Comment: Add more code and template samples

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It is much easier for us to help you if you provide some of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can in the interface specify the type as string or array if you want to.

```
skills: string|string[];
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comments, you might have to cast your variable to do certain operations only available to the specific type:

```
// Convert from string to string[]
this.candidate.skills = (<string>this.candidate.skills).split(', ');
```

Comment: Thanks . It seems to have solved the problem. I also needed a little bit of assertion to do: `this.candidate.skills = (<string>this.candidate.skills).split(', ');`. Without it , the split method still wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The interface that i implement:

```
export class Candidate {
id: number;
name: string;
skills: string|string[]; }
```

In the component i try to upload my data through a service.
The code in the component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CandidatesService } from '../candidates.service';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Candidate } from '../candidate';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-candidates-adding',
  templateUrl: './candidates-adding.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./candidates-adding.component.css']
})
export class CandidatesAddingComponent implements OnInit {
  candidate: Candidate = new Candidate();

  constructor(private candidatesService: CandidatesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  saveCandidate(): void {
    if(this.candidate.skills.indexOf(', ') >= 0) {
      this.candidate.skills = this.candidate.skills.split(', '); 
    }
    this.candidatesService.addCandidate(this.candidate).subscribe();
  }
}
```

And in the template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="candidate.name" placeholder="name" minlength="4">
<input [(ngModel)]="candidate.skills" placeholder="name" minlength="1">
<button (click)="saveCandidate()">Adauga candidat</button>
```

Comment: You can add this as part of your question instead of an answer if you'd like

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem, I was using typescript v.4.4.3.

```
this.candidate.skills = ((this.candidate.skills as unknown) as string).split(',')
```

so, first I set it to unknown and then to the type I want (here, for example, to string), and that's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got here trying to convert a string|string[] to an int.  I found 3 solutions.

```
const trouble: string|string[] = "1234"
const id = Number(trouble)
const id = parseInt(trouble.toString())
const id = parseInt(trouble.toString(), 10)
```

Comment: How does this handle the `string[]`-types?

Comment: I don't think the Number() usage is reliable, but the .toString() flattens the array to a string.